# Class folder not accepted into Matlab's path

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to use the [Gramm Toolbox](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54465-gramm-complete-data-visualization-toolbox-ggplot2-r-like) to do some advanced data plotting, however I cannot seem to get even a simple "hello world" plot done with it.

Namely, when I run any of the code cells in its examples.m file, I'm met with this path-related error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'parse_aes'.
Error in gramm (line 177)
            obj.aes=parse_aes(varargin{:});
```

This despite having added the Gramm folder (c:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\gramm\; which is a parent folder to the @gramm folder) to Matlab's path recursively, i.e. with all of its subdirectories. This, according to the readme, is the only required installation step.

I'm guessing the problem comes from the class folder/definition, but unfortunately I know nothing about object-oriented programming.

I'm running Matlab 2016a, with the statistics and the curve fitting toolboxes installed as per the toolbox requirements.

Can anyone suggest something else I can try? (there seems to be no direct/prompt support from the code author himself)

Comment: Thanks but I already added the toolbox folder (and its subfolders, which contain the parse_aes.m file in question) to the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after having fixed the path according to Suever's reply (needed to be added non-recursively), I still got the same error.

A hint was the message that Matlab was displaying after restarting it:

```
Warning: Found directory Private in directory c:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\gramm\@gramm. Private
directory names must be spelled 'private'.
```

It's unclear why the subfolder was named with a capital P, as the downloaded ZIP has it with lower case. At any rate, after renaming that subfolder 'private', all the examples worked as expected.

Comment: Did you rename that? Because if you look at the toolbox code, it is `private`

Comment: No, I just de-archived the downloaded ZIP - no idea how that uppercase P made its way in there!

Comment: Thanks again for your involvement though!

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to add all directories recursively to the path, just add the top-level directory containing the `@gramm` class folder.

If you add the subdirectories, than the class definition file, [`@gramm/gramm.m`](https://github.com/piermorel/gramm/blob/master/%40gramm/gramm.m) will exist on the path, and that will be used directly when you call `gramm` and all other methods defined in the `@gramm` folder (and `@gramm/private`) will not be properly associated with that class instance.

If you re-read the installation instructions, it does not mention adding the directories *recursively*, just adding the top-level directory:

> ... add the folder containing the `@gramm` class folder to your Matlab path (using the GUI or `addpath()`)

Comment: I see - maybe it was just excess of zeal on my part adding everything to the path. However, after having removed those from the path and adding just the top-level directory as you say, running the examples still produces the same path error!

Comment: Have you tried restarting MATLAB or running `clear all; clear classes;`? Sometimes class definitions can be pretty sticky within a MATLAB session.

Comment: I found what the problem was. I guess it's best I just describe that as an answer to my own question.